# Append text in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jlabel

How would I go about achieving the effect of JTextArea with JLabel?

I want the output to be displayed every time the button is clicked on the next line down instead of replacing what text is already there, i.e. like an append method for JLabel?

I just want it to follow the same behavior as JTextArea.append.

Also I want to add hyperlink to each line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Use HTML formatting in the label by starting the text with prefix `<html><body>` (possibly add some in-line styles in the `body` opening element).
2. Add each line, ending with `<br>` or `<p>` (or `<li>` if adding `<ul><li>` to the prefix).

---

See also [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html). For such gems as..

[image: HTML Button]

Answer (score 11):

You can do that as follows,

```
label.setText(label.getText() + "text u want to append");
```

on each event.

Comment: Does not fulfill requirement *"on the next line down"*.

Comment: Only way is to use HTML formatting for that as @AndrewThompson stated

Comment: I disagree it is the *only* way.  You might extend `JLabel` or attempt to style a `JTextArea` to appear (and 'feel' - not focusable etc.) like a `JLabel`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Not for novice users, we should first use what SDK has provided and if it is not satisfying the requirements we can extend it.