# display array values in one jlabel

Tags: java, arrays, swing, for-loop, jlabel

I would like display the values of my String array in one Jlabel.

I've tried with a loop (for) but, the result is the new letter overwrites the previous.
I do not understand how I could displaying the letters following.

labelWord is the variableName of my Jlabel.

```
String myArray[] = new String[4];
myArray[0] = "h";
myArray[1] = "e";
myArray[2] = "l";
myArray[3] = "l";
myArray[4] = "o";
```

and my loop :

```
for (int j = 0; j <= myArray.length; j++) {
    labelWord.setText(myArray[j]);
}
```

Comment: Simply try `labelWord.setText(labelWord.getText()+myArray[j]);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append text in JLabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717121/append-text-in-jlabel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because you set the label value with the 1st String, then the second one, then the 3rd one... You need to concatene all your String into one then set the label text with this value:

```
String value ="";
for (int j = 0; j <= myArray.length; j++) {
                value += myArray[j];}
labelWord.setText( value );
```

Note: you can also use a StringBuilder instead of concatenating directly to the String.

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the text each time you call `labelWord.setText()`.

Just build the whole string before you set it

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int j = 0; j <= myArray.length; j++) {
    builder.append(myArray[j]);
}
labelWord.setText(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting it yourself by calling `setText()` everytime in loop. you need to append it to the text by doing:

```
labelWord.setText(labelWord.getText() + myArray[j]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Kindly select one answer that helped you as accepted. have fun coding :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this without using StringBuilder or anything like that would be to use another string variable

```
String myLabelText = "";
for (int j = 0; j <= myArray.length; j++) {
            myLabelText = myLabelText + myArray[j];
}
labelWord.setText( myLabelText );
```

You were essentially just changing the value of the label for every item in the array, not adding it to the end

Answer (score 1):

*One More Interesting Way you would like to know(**In your CASE**)*

```
String arr[]={"h","e","l","l","o"};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr).replaceAll("[\\]\\[,\\s]", ""));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
hello
```

*So directly,*

```
jlabel.setText(Arrays.toString(arr).replaceAll("[\\]\\[,\\s]", ""));
```

---

*NOTE:
This will not be applicable if array elements contains space(Sorry for that).*