# How to add text to JLabel

Tags: java, jlabel

I am creating a book reader, which takes the content of a file and sends it to an Object[]. I want this to be displayed, line by line on my page. I'm considering a loop of some sort that will add text to the label, but here's my question: How to I add text to the end of a JLabel, rather than setting the whole thing?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717121/append-text-in-jlabel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getText()` to retrieve what's there, and then `setText()` to set the new value.

So to add `something` to the end, you'd do

```
label.setText(label.getText()+"something");
```

Remember you'll probably be wanting to add a space in the middle. If you've got a new `String str` you want to append, you will probably want

```
label.setText(label.getText()+" "+str);
```

to make sure you add the space and then the contents of `str`.

Answer (score 0):

@chiastic-security answer is the better one. Here is another solution that I believe will save some memory.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Object[] objectArray;

    for (Object o : objectArray) { // loop through the Object array
        sb.append(o.toString() + " "); // append each index of the Object array to the StringBuilder
    }

    label.setText(sb.toString());
```