# How do I append a new text with previous text in JLable in Java

Tags: java

Is it possible to display a new text after the previously displayed text in JLabel? When first time Jbutton is clicked "Apple" should be displayed, next time when the JButton is clicked "Orange" should be displayed below "Apple" in the same JLabel and third time when clicked "Grapes" should be displayed below "Orange". Like this

```
Apple
Orange
Grapes
```

Comment: The same way you "append" a `String`. What do you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add text to JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624270/how-to-add-text-to-jlabel)

Answer (score 0):

Just set an static integer variable "counter" that counts every time you press the Button and append the new String to the previous ones.

- If counter = 1 -> Label should be "Apple"
- If counter = 2 -> Label should be "Apple\nOrange"
- If counter = 3 -> Label should be "Apple\nOrange\nGrapes"

Comment: For a more complet solution, use an array with the words in the correct position to simply `label += array[counter]`. Just saying ;)

Comment: This is working. "<html>"+JLable.getText()+"<br/>"+[string]+["<br/>"]+</html>