# How do I display the numbers in a for loop in a jLabel?

Tags: java, swing, for-loop

```
    int intStartingNumber = Integer.parseInt(this.txtInputStartingNumber.getText());
    int intEndingNumber = Integer.parseInt(this.txtInputEndingNumber.getText());

    for (int x = intStartingNumber; x <= intEndingNumber; x = x + 1) {
        System.out.print(x + " ");
        this.lblOutputNumbers.setText(x + " ");
    }
```

Hi this is my code how come it won't set my jLabel as all the numbers in the for loop but when i print it out, all the numbers show up. In the jLabel only whatever is inputted as the EndingNumber is printed out in the jLabel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RE

> In the jLabel only whatever is inputted as the EndingNumber is printed out in the jLabel.

```
for (int x = intStartingNumber; x <= intEndingNumber; x++) {
    System.out.print(x + " ");
    this.lblOutputNumbers.setText(lblOutputNumbers.getText() + " " + x);
}
```

The trick here is JLabel does not have an appendText function, but you can call the `JLabel.getText()` function inside of its setText function to append text to the label.

This answer stems from [Append text in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717121/append-text-in-jlabel)

Comment: Oh I get it now. But how come when I try to type in the lblOutputNumber.getText part in, the getText part creates an error  EDIT: I got it to work by putting the () after getText  thanks!